# mongodb query to find field - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

How would I structure a query for mongodB to make a 'stored procedure' or make the request to select an id which is marked active and then delete that field immediately or mark it as inactive; whichever one has the better performance. Here is the collection structure:

```
    db = server.GetDatabase("test")
    siteCollection = db("test")
    collection = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("siteids")
    Dim book As BsonDocument = New BsonDocument() _
                    .Add("siteid", BsonValue.Create(BsonType.String)) _
                    .Add("active", BsonValue.Create(BsonType.String))
    collection.Insert(book)
```

I found the java version and not sure if this will work and what is .net syntax

```
db.things.find( { x : 4 } , { j : 1 } )
```

This apparantly finds records where x = 4 but only return where j = 1 so I want one siteid where active = 'N'

Thanks; here is what I have come up with thus far:

```
    ' Dim squery = Query.EQ("active", "Y")

    Dim squery = Query.EQ("active", "Y")
    Dim ssort = SortBy.Null
    Dim uupdate = Update.[Set]("active", "N")
    Dim result = collection.FindAndModify(squery, ssort, uupdate)


    ' Dim dresult = collection.FindAs(Of BsonDocument)(squery)
    Dim newSiteId As String = dresult.Count
```

As you can see the first line commented out I thought a simple select would be implemented but that comes back null. Then with the second last statement commented out that too returned value Null.

Comment: It sounds like you'd need to use `findAndModify`. There's some documentation in C# here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/. You'll need a `Query`, and `Update`.

Comment: thanks that helped...still stuck a little

Comment: whats the problem with it?